# ORA-01537. i want to search where the file is included, again

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

i asked this question. but i can't solve. i want to ask again.

```
SQL> alter tablespace java add datafile 'd:/programming/java.dbf';
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01537: cannot add file 'd:/programming/java.dbf' - file already part of database


SQL> select TABLESPACE_NAME, FILE_NAME,STATUS 
 from dba_data_files
 where UPPER(FILE_NAME) like '%JAVA.DBF';
no rows selected.
```

i just want to know the statement searching where the file is included.
my oracle is 11g.

Comment: but you marked it solved.

Comment: Please don't make duplicate questions. And don't mark a question as solved if it isn't

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a temporary tablespace using a tempfile with the name java.dbf?

Check with:

select file_name, tablespace_name, status from dba_temp_files;

If the datafile resides within temporary tablespace, it on show up when you query dba_data_files, therefore yes, the file may already exists.